# Display Text through a loop in a label

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to display text through this label.  There are two items of text in POPart.PODetail.Comment.Count, however my code only displays the (1) comment and not (0).  and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```
    If POPart.PoDetail.Comment.Count > 0 Then

        For i As Integer = 0 To POPart.PoDetail.Comment.Count - 1

            lblcomments.Text = POPart.PoDetail.Comment(i).Comment


        Next
    End If
```

Comment: You are overwriting the comment from (0) with the comment from (1). Try something joining them together to see it better: `lblcomments.Text &= POPart.PoDetail.Comment(i).Comment`

Comment: it worked thank you so much.  How can i display the order backwards ?? @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo

Comment: `For i As Integer = POPart.PoDetail.Comment.Count  to 0 Step -1`

Comment: Oops, sorry I just woke up, its actually: `For i As Integer = POPart.PoDetail.Comment.Count-1 to 0 Step -1`

Answer (score 1):

The comment at position (0) **is** being displayed but it is quickly being overwritten by the comment at position (1). Depending on how you want to display the data you can concatenate the values together to display both at once:

```
If POPart.PoDetail.Comment.Count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To POPart.PoDetail.Comment.Count - 1
        lblcomments.Text &= POPart.PoDetail.Comment(i).Comment
    Next
End If
```

**Bonus:** If you want to display the comments in the reverse order you only have to change your for loop structure to start at the tail end of the comments and work your way back to index (0):

```
If POPart.PoDetail.Comment.Count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = POPart.PoDetail.Comment.Count-1 to 0 Step -1
        lblcomments.Text &= POPart.PoDetail.Comment(i).Comment
    Next
End If
```

Comment: or concatenate the other way: lblcomments.Text = POPart.PoDetail.Comment(i).Comment & lblcomments.Text